# How to isolate some Containers from Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

With a Horizontal Pod **Autoscaler** implemented for the **Deployment** running a **Pod** with two different containers: **Containers-A** and **Contaner-B**, I want to make sure that it only scales the number of Containers-A. The number of Containers-B should always be the same and not being effected by the Pod's **Autoscaler**. I wonder if isolating the Container-B from Autoscaler would be possible. If so, how to achieve it?

```
kubectl autoscale my-deployment --min=10 --max=15 --cpu-percent=80
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests **"Horizontal Pod Autoscaler"** scales pods, not containers.

However, I do not see a reason why you would want this behavior.

[You should have more than one container in a Pod only if those containers are tightly coupled together and need to share resources.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#understanding-pods)
The fact that you want to scale container A and B independently, tells me that those containers are not tightly coupled.

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Deployment A that manages Pods with container A.
   The Autoscaler will only scale the pods for this deployment.
2. Deployment B that manages Pods with container B. This deployment will not be affected by the autoscaler.